# What is the difference between typeof and the is keyword?

Tags: c#, generics, types

What's the exact difference between the two?

```
// When calling this method with GetByType<MyClass>()

public bool GetByType<T>() {
    // this returns true:
    return typeof(T).Equals(typeof(MyClass));

    // this returns false:
    return typeof(T) is MyClass;
}
```

Comment: Warning - This won't work if you need to use inheritance.  Using `typeof(AClass).IsAssignableFrom(typeof(T))` will solve that.  See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.isassignablefrom.aspx.

Comment: @Will thanks for the info. Wouldn't matter in my specific case, but good to know!

Answer (score 61, accepted):

You should use `is AClass` on instances and not to compare types:

```
var myInstance = new AClass();
var isit = myInstance is AClass; //true
```

`is` works also with base-classes and interfaces:

```
MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream();

bool isStream = stream is Stream; //true
bool isIDispo = stream is IDisposable; //true
```

Comment: Thanks. Nice, brief and comprehensive explanation.

Answer (score 33):

The `is` keyword checks if an object is of a certain type. `typeof(T)` is of type `Type`, and not of type `AClass`.

Check the MSDN for the [is keyword](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/scekt9xw%28v=VS.100%29.aspx) and the [typeof keyword](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/58918ffs.aspx)

Comment: Unfortunately I can only accept one. Least I can do is upvote everyone else. Thank you!

Answer (score 25):

`typeof(T)` returns a `Type` instance. and the `Type` is never equal to `AClass`

```
var t1 = typeof(AClass)); // t1 is a "Type" object

var t2 = new AClass(); // t2 is a "AClass" object

t2 is AClass; // true
t1 is AClass; // false, because of t1 is a "Type" instance, not a "AClass" instance
```

Comment: Unfortunately I can only accept one. Least I can do is upvote everyone else. Thank you!

Answer (score 11):

- typeof(T) returns a Type object
- Type is not AClass and can never be since Type doesn't derive from AClass

your first statement is right

Comment: Unfortunately I can only accept one. Least I can do is upvote everyone else. Thank you!

Answer (score 10):

`typeof` returns a `Type` object describing `T` which is not of type `AClass` hence the `is` returns false.

Comment: Unfortunately I can only accept one. Least I can do is upvote everyone else. Thank you!

Answer (score 10):

- first compares the two Type objects (types are themselves object in .net)
- second, if well written (myObj is AClass) check compatibility between two types.  if myObj is an instance of a class inheriting from AClass, it will return true.

typeof(T) is AClass returns false because typeof(T) is Type and AClass does not inherit from Type

Comment: Unfortunately I can only accept one. Least I can do is upvote everyone else. Thank you!